# Display not found page 404 on specific Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

Here is my case, I'm making some experiments with post types, basically I created a post type called Slider where the featured image is will display in the slide.

Now, when user type something like domain.com/slider/slide1, or try to reach the slider post, I want to display a not found page instead of the single page, or the index in case I dont have the post single page.

Is it possible to achieve?

**Solved!**

Thanks to Saif Bechan, I could solve my problem,

Basically I used this function

```
 add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect');
 function my_template_redirect() {
 global $wp_query, $post;
 if(is_singular('Slider')) 
 {
      $wp_query->set_404();
   }
 }
```

Where Slider is the Post Type name,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a script that wil; display a good 404 page for certain pages. Now I do not yet know what custom post types are, as I am just starting, but I think you can edit the script to fit your needs.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect');
function my_template_redirect()
{
    global $wp_query, $post;

    if (is_author() || is_attachment() || is_day() || is_page())
    {
        $wp_query->set_404();
    }

    if (is_feed())
    {
        $author     = get_query_var('author_name');
        $attachment = get_query_var('attachment');
        $attachment = (empty($attachment)) ? get_query_var('attachment_id') : $attachment;
        $day        = get_query_var('day');
        $page   = get_query_var('page');

        if (!empty($author) || !empty($attachment) || !empty($day) || !empty($page))
        {
            $wp_query->set_404();
            $wp_query->is_feed = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you can do something with this this code. I use this in my `functions.php` to block access to the different parts of the website. They are also blocked for feeds.

Comment: I used your idea to solve the problem, using the is_singular function instead, that returns "true" if is_single(), is_page() or is_attachment(). http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular thanks a ton

Comment: Glad I could. I thought this script would come of some use, as it also deals with 404 pages. Ill remember the function you created also for custom post types, maybe I will need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy your index.php file and name it 404.php. Then if a page or attachment page wasn't found it would use the 404.php page which would just be a copy of the index.php file.

Comment: uh! so simple that I couldn't think about it! however I would like another more technical solution! but probably at the end of the day I will go for it!  Muchas Gracias :)!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly create a page template named 404, then use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-template/ which will allow you to choose it as the template for that page.